# Bash Script Understanding

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to figure what exactly is the bash code mentioned below trying to do, specially the `[-z $M ]` part. here M is a variable with a value

```
if [ -z $M ] ; then
    can not find module directory
    exit 1
```

Comment: Do a text search [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Conditional-Expressions.html) for `-z`.

Answer (score 7):

1. `man test` <kbd>Enter</kbd>
2. press <kbd>/</kbd><kbd>-</kbd><kbd>z</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

you see:

```
-z STRING
              the length of STRING is zero
```

so your script does, if `$M` length==0, then exit with status code `1`

Comment: So a correct Python translation for this should be somewhat like this: if $M == 0: print "Not Valid" close() is this correct Kent ?

Comment: That was the kindest way of saying RTFM I've ever seen :D

Comment: @Nick I think it is clear enough, in any language it is a very easy if check. if a variable length==0, exit the program with a certain code.

Comment: @Nick More like `if len($M) == 0: print "Not Valid"` for Python.

Comment: Thanks everyone! appreciate your help.

Comment: And I hope the downvoter could explain a bit, so that I could learn.

Comment: -1 How would the OP know that `[` is an alias of `test`? For that matter, it doesn't even look like a command, so looking up a man page for it wouldn't seem an obvious thing to do. This answer strikes me as somewhat condescending.

Comment: @IMSoP have you ever read the `man test`? don't give it too much time, just read the 1st 10 lines, the `[ EXPRESSION ]` is clearly written there. he doesn't know, that is why he came and ask. And we post answer, and let him know.

Comment: @Kent **I** knew that `[` was an alias of `test`, but the OP didn't. So rather than the condescending instructions, you could have simply mentioned the fact in your answer.

Comment: Basically, I disagree with @JiriKremser and those who upvoted their comment that this is any kinder than writing "RTFM" and making it a hyperlink to http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?test

Comment: @IMSoP  my last sentence in my answer explained what does the script do. the man page explain why `-z` means length==0. I don't really know as an answer, which part deserves a downvote. anyway, this is a pretty easy question, I think OP has got his answer.  we should not type so  much on this. I believe that your vote with your personal opinion. It's ok.

Comment: @Kent I think my downvote was more about tone than content per se. Why not just say "`[` is an alias of `test`, so you can look up the standard options with `man test`, where you will find the following:" rather than all the "press this then this" stuff? But like you say, clearly just one opinion.

Comment: +1 for the answer and -1 for he question. The question doesn't show any effort for search a solution.

Answer (score 3):

As others have said, it's using the `test` command (aka `[`) to check whether a string is blank. At least, that's what it's trying to do; because the string (`$M`) isn't double-quoted, it's actually doing something slightly different. Without double-quotes, the value of `$M` undergoes word splitting and wildcard expansion after it's replaced, so it might not be treated as a simple string (which the `-z` operator works on) with ... potentially unexpected consequences. Let me run through some of the possibilities:

- If the value of `$M` is a single word (non-blank) without wildcards (`*` and `?`), everything works as expected.
- If the value of `$M` is zero-length (blank), the test command only sees a single argument (`-z`); when test is only given a single argument, it simply tests whether it's blank -- it's not, so it evaluates to true.

  This happens to be the expected result in this case, but it's purely by coincidence, and with many other operators it wouldn't be the right result. For instance, `[ -n $M ]` (which looks like it should test whether `$M` is *non*blank), `[ -e $M ]` (which looks like it should test whether `$M` is the name of a file/directory) etc will all evaluate to true if `$M` is blank.
- If the value of `$M` consists entirely of whitespace (but isn't empty), it gets eliminated before `test` sees it, and `test` evaluates to true (see previous case). This might or might not be what the scripter had in mind.
- If the value of `$M` has multiple words, `test` will attempt to evaluate it as (part of) an expression. It will probably not be a valid expression, in which case `test` will print an error and return false (which is right ... sort of).

  On the other hand, if it is a valid expression... Suppose for example you had, `M='= -z`; `test` would evaluate the expression `-z = -z` which would be true, not at all what the scripter had in mind.
- If the value of `$M` has any wildcards, the shell will try to match them against files and pass `test` the list of matches; it'll try to evaluate them as an expression (see previous case), probably giving an error and returning false (again, sort of right).

  Mind you, if you happen to have set the nullglob shell option and the wildcard doesn't match any files, the shell will replace it with null, and the script will act as though "u*n*m*a*t*c*h*e*d" was the empty string.

The lesson here: if you don't want your scripts to behave in weird and unexpected ways, double-quote your variable references!

Comment: you could also use double square brackets [[ ]] to prevent the wildcard shenanigans (if you're a bash/ksh man. older shells would probably blow up)

Comment: @stringy05: Yes, `[[ ]]` cleans up a lot of the sharp edges in `[ ]`'s syntax, but there are still a few cases where double-quotes matter. For example, `[[ $a = $b ]]` will treat `$b` as a pattern (if it contains wildcards), while `[[ "$a" = "$b" ]]` does a straight equality comparison.

Comment: good point @GordonDavisson, I seem to remember double brackets are ok when using `==` rather than `=`. When I was writing shell scripts all the time I was totally paranoid. I would have done this: `[[ "${a}" ==  "${b}" ]]`

Comment: `==` and `=` are identical when used in a `[[ ... ]]` expression.

Answer (score 1):

The `[` is actually a standard Unix command (probably implemented internally in Bash, but available whatever shell you are using). It is an alias for the command `test`, so its manual entry can be found by typing `man test`. Here's [an online copy of that manual page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?test).

When invoked as `[`, `test` will generally expect its last argument to be a `]`, just for good looks, so `[ -z $M ]` is equivalent to `test -z $M`.

In this case, the `-z` argument causes `test` to return true if the following argument is a string of length zero. The variable `$M`, defined further up the script, can thus be tested for a valid value.

Answer (score 0):

It checks whether the content of variable `M` is an empty string.

Check this [link](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html)